# convert this function from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, function

need this function in php :/ and i'm struggling with >>>= operators!?
please help to convert this javascript function to php - thank you <3

```
function calcValues(variant) {
    var shape = variant & 0xFF;
    variant >>>= 8;
    var pattern = variant & 0xFF;
    variant >>>= 8;
    var baseColor = variant & 0xFF;
    variant >>>= 8;
    var patternColor = variant & 0xFF;

    console.log(shape, pattern,baseColor,patternColor);
}
```

Comment: You can replace `>>>= 8` with `//= 256`.

Comment: can you show me some code in a snippet, // is commenting in php

Comment: ah, found the solution:

$variant = intdiv($variant, 256);

Comment: Just use `>>=`. `>>>`/`>>>=` is a [JS thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift) that doesn't have a PHP equivalent, and thinking about what this code actually _does_ I have no idea why they used `>>>` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function calcValues($variant) {
    $shape = $variant & 0xFF;
    $variant=$variant >>  8;
    $pattern = $variant & 0xFF;
    $variant=$variant >> 8;
    $baseColor = $variant & 0xFF;
    $variant=$variant >> 8;
    $patternColor = $variant & 0xFF;

    //console.log($shape, $pattern,$baseColor,$patternColor);
    var_dump([$shape, $pattern,$baseColor,$patternColor]);
}
calcValues(65535);
var_dump(0xFF);
?>
```

by mistake i deleted the "$variant= "  .. this edited version gives me 255 255 0 0  (the same result for your javascript version ,using 65535 value)

here you have the complete guide of other functions
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 1):

IMO Constantin's answer is objectively best for OP's specific case. But...

While I maintain that you don't need `>>>` equivalent for the given code, and `>>` will work just fine, and have the further warning that using a `>>>` equivalent on negative integer values across languages/systems with different integer/word sizes will have undefined behaviour, here is a function that replicates the behaviour of JS's `>>>` operator.

```php
// formatted decbin
function fdecbin($input) {
    $out = decbin($input);
    $len = ((int)ceil(strlen($out)/8))*8;
    $out = str_pad($out, $len, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return implode(' ', str_split($out, 8));
}

// zero-padded right bit shift
function zeroshift($input, $bits) {
    if( $bits == 0 ) { return $input; }
    $mask = PHP_INT_MAX >> ($bits - 1);
    return $input >> $bits & $mask;
}

$i = -110;

var_dump(
    fdecbin($i),
    fdecbin($i>>2),
    fdecbin(zeroshift($i, 2))
);
```

Output:

```
string(71) "11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 10010010"
string(71) "11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11100100"
string(71) "00111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11100100"
```

Again, please carefully consider what the code is actually doing before using an obscure, esoteric operator/operation like `>>>`, or this code that replicates it.